# Cross join in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying this

```
$this->db->join('tableTwo as b','','CROSS');
$result = $this->db->get('tableOne as a')->result();
```

Some solution?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Join Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for cross join in codeigniter:

```
$this->db->join('tableTwo as b','true');
$result = $this->db->get('tableOne as a')->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

### In codeigniter 3, You can add cross join query builder by

```
$this->db->join('tableTwo as b','1=1');                    //true relation
$result = $this->db->get('tableOne as a')->result();
```

### Or by passing an array in from method or get methods

```
$result = $this->db->get(['tableOne as a','tableTwo as b'])->result();
```

### or

```
$result = $this->db->from(['tableOne as a','tableTwo as b'])
get()->result();     //by this method you can add as many table you want to join
```

or by passing one table in from and other in get method

```
$result = $this->db->from('tableOne as a')
get('tableTwo as b')->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use it this way:

```
$this->db->join('tableTwo as b','true');
$result = $this->db->get('tableOne as a')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones coming to see the answer for **Codeigniter 4**:

```
// tableOne is defined in the model
$this->model->join('tableTwo', 'column_x= column_y', 'cross');
```

The first parameter is a table name, the next parameter is the condition for the join and the third parameter is the join type.

So if you have a SQL sentence like this:

```
cross join producto_resumen_color on prre_id = prco_prre_id
```

You wold do this:

```
->join('producto_resumen_color','prre_id = prco_prre_id', 'cross')
```

You can find more information in the CI'S User guide.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#join

```
join($table, $cond[, $type = ''[, $escape = NULL]])

Parameters: 

    $table (string) – Table name to join
    $cond (string) – The JOIN ON condition
    $type (string) – The JOIN type
    $escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers
```